# Can a canvas handle double numbers as points?

Tags: java, java-canvas

Is a `canvas` capable of handling `double` numbers like `0.5, 10.4` etc? Or would this be rounded internally to an integer (if yes, how?).

I'm asking because I think that elements on a canvas are represented as pixels.

And as a pixel is always size `1x1` (correct me if I'm wrong), is there any advantage of more accurate drawing if I supply `double` values to a canvas function rather than `integer`?

Comment: Yes, it's called sub-pixel rendering, and it's better be avoided for the reasons described in [this article](http://seb.ly/2011/02/html5-canvas-sprite-optimisation/).

Comment: Well I don't think it is correct, in general, giving pixels in `double`. Apparent analogy: There are 100 cents in a dollar; Saying 50.5 cents doesn't make sense, since it implies that cents can be further divided which is not true in standard terms. Similarly using 0.5, 10.4 etc for pixel doesn't make sense, since it implies that pixel can be sub-divided, which is not true in standard terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fractional coordinates are possible, as the browser can use them to interpolate things on the pixel level. For outlines this results in anti-aliasing, while for interior pixels this interpolation might make things a bit fuzzy. Particularly if your object is not formed by individual pixels, but instead something rather smooth, e.g. a circle, then rendering at the sub-pixel level can give users an impression of more resolution than actually physically possible, due to the way we perceived the anti-aliased outline.

But as [raina77ow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1229023/raina77ow) stated [in a comment to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614817/can-a-canvas-handle-double-numbers-as-points#comment22146646_15614817), this comes at a cost in terms of added work by the browser, which causes a performance penalty. So I'd use these guidelines to make the decision:

- If the thing to draw is made up of regions of pixels, all of the filled with the same color, and high contrast between adjacent regions, then I'd use integral coordinates since double coordinates will cause blurring which might look bad.
- If you only draw a few things not too often, and geometrical precision is desirable, then use double coordinates.
- If you have to worry about performance, then use integer coordinates.

As your question is also tagged [java](/questions/tagged/java): Have a look at the [`RenderingHints`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/RenderingHints.html). The stroke control setting will control whether coordinates are rounded in some cases or not, while the antialiasing and interpolation settings will affect how fractional positions are rendered, the first for vector outlines and the second for raster images.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think that a canvas can hand double points. A work around though is to cast the double to a int. This way, the number is treated like a int and it works like usual. The casting looks like this:
`db.drawImage(image, (int) x, (int) y;`
I use this in my games and it works great.